# How can i set on child route as default route in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a route '/signup' under which there are two children routes 'fighter' and 'companion'. When a user comes to 'signup', I want one of them to be the default, like either 'fighter' or 'companion'. How can I achieve this?

This is code

```
    {
      path: "/signup",
      element:
        auth.isLoggedIn && JSON.parse(auth?.token) ? (
          <Navigate to={"/fighter"} replace={true} />
        ) : (
          <SignupLayout />
        ),
      children: [
        {
          path: "fighter",
          element: <FighterSignup />,
        },
        {
          path: "companion",
          element: <CompanionSignup />,
        },
      ],
    },
```